# Converting text to hexadecimal on mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, encoding, hex

I am trying to convert a text to hexadecimal characters in order to build a dmg on mac.
I'm getting burned by the fact that hexadecimals do not seem to refer to the same characters on mac and windows for ascii characters > 127. And it seems like the basic javascript functions only give the "windows" translation.
I need the "mac" translation to hexadecimal...

I'm doing this so far:

```
const fileData = await parseJson(readFile(item.file, "utf-8"))
const buttonsStr = labelToHex(fileData.lang)

function labelToHex(label: string) {
  return hexEncode(label).toString().toUpperCase()
}

function hexEncode(str: string) {
  let i
  let result = ""

  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    result += unicodeToHex(str.charCodeAt(i))
  }

  return result
}

function unicodeToHex(unicode: number) {
  const hex = unicode.toString(16)
  return ("0" + hex).slice(-2)
}
```

**If I pass in:** Français éàè
**I get:** 46 72 61 6e e7 61 69 73 e9 e0 e8
**but when I read it back, I get:** FranÀais È‡Ë
**I'm expecting to get:** 46 72 61 6e 8d 61 69 73 8E 88 8f
**so that reading it back gives:** 46 72 61 6e e7 61 69 73 e9 e0 e8

This corresponds to those sheets:
https://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ext-mac.htm
https://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ext-pc.htm

Nonetheless, I was not able to find either a npm package that would translate to hex based on the OS or just some obscure js function I still haven't stumbled upon?
I'm running out of ideas and just about to do:

```
function unicodeToHex(unicode: number) {
  if (unicode < 128) {
    const hex = unicode.toString(16)
    return ("0" + hex).slice(-2)
  }

  if (unicode === 233) { return "8E" }//é
  if (unicode === 224) { return "88" }//à
  if (unicode === 232) { return "8F" }//è

  return "3F" //?
}
```

but I would really like to avoid that...

Comment: charCodeAt returns a unicode value, this is way more than your 1 byte trimming involves.  If you just want hex values of a string in node,. try this ->  `new Buffer('Français éàè').toString('hex')`  = `4672616ec3a761697320c3a9c3a0c3a8`, that is 16 bytes, for you 11 character string.

Comment: it seems logical, but it still doesn't work in my dmg.. I get garbage instead of éàè: √ß√˘ß©ß®_ Which makes me think that it might be because the dmg doesn't know it's utf8?

Comment: `dmg doesn't know it's utf8`  Very possible,.. If so there are tools to convert utf8 into a selected code page,.. So if you can find out what codepage dmg files use, you can use something like -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/codepage

Comment: I also have some working exemples (which are the hardcoded values I am trying to make dynamic): 7072 8E73 656E 7465 = présente (where é = 8E, so the mac version) I get: 7072 C3A9 7365 6E74 65 instead
and 82B5 82DC 82B7 = します (shimasu) where each char is a 2 hex...  I get E38197 E381BE E38199 instead, which is rather 3 hex per char... so the hardcoded values differ from what I get from toString("hex")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to do it, thanks to the code pages, as stated by @Keith

```
const cptable = require("codepage")
function hexEncode(str: string, lang: string, langWithRegion: string) {
  let code
  let hex
  let i
  const macCodePages = getMacCodePage(lang, langWithRegion)
  let result = ""

  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    try {
      code = getMacCharCode(str, i, macCodePages)
      if (code === undefined) {
        hex = "3F" //?
      } else {
        hex = code.toString(16)
      }

      result += hex
    } catch (e) {
      debug("there was a problem while trying to convert a char to hex: " + e)
      result += "3F" //?
    }
  }

  return result
}

function getMacCodePage(lang: string, langWithRegion: string) {
  switch (lang) {
    case "ja": //japanese
      return [10001] //Apple Japanese
    case "zh": //chinese
      if (langWithRegion === "zh_CN") {
        return [10008] //Apple Simplified Chinese (GB 2312)
      }
      return [10002] //Apple Traditional Chinese (Big5)
    case "ko": //korean
      return [10003] //Apple Korean
    case "ar": //arabic
    case "ur": //urdu
      return [10004] //Apple Arabic
    case "he": //hebrew
      return [10005] //Apple Hebrew
    case "el": //greek
    case "elc": //greek
      return [10006] //Apple Greek
    case "ru": //russian
    case "be": //belarussian
    case "sr": //serbian
    case "bg": //bulgarian
    case "uz": //uzbek
      return [10007] //Apple Macintosh Cyrillic
    case "ro": //romanian
      return [10010] //Apple Romanian
    case "uk": //ukrainian
      return [10017] //Apple Ukrainian
    case "th": //thai
      return [10021] //Apple Thai
    case "et": //estonian
    case "lt": //lithuanian
    case "lv": //latvian
    case "pl": //polish
    case "hu": //hungarian
    case "cs": //czech
    case "sk": //slovak
      return [10029] //Apple Macintosh Central Europe
    case "is": //icelandic
    case "fo": //faroese
      return [10079] //Apple Icelandic
    case "tr": //turkish
      return [10081] //Apple Turkish
    case "hr": //croatian
    case "sl": //slovenian
      return [10082] //Apple Croatian
    default:
      return [10000] //Apple Macintosh Roman
  }
}

function getMacCharCode(str: string, i: number, macCodePages: any) {
  let code = str.charCodeAt(i)
  let j
  if (code < 128) {
    code = str.charCodeAt(i)
  }
  else if (code < 256) {
    //codepage 10000 = mac OS Roman
    code = cptable[10000].enc[str[i]]
  }
  else {
    for (j = 0; j < macCodePages.length; j++) {
      code = cptable[macCodePages[j]].enc[str[i]]
      if (code !== undefined) {
        break
      }
    }
  }

  return code
}
```